# ListView has been removed from React Native , even if i'm not using it

Tags: react-native

I'm new to React natives , i have this issue saying : Invariant Violation: **ListView has been removed from React Native.**

I'm not even using ListView on my project , i'll share with you my package.json

````
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "postinstall": "cp node_modules/@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome.js node_modules/@expo/vector-icons/Fontisto.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-inline-import": "^3.0.0",
    "expo": "~37.0.3",
    "idx": "^2.5.6",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.2",
    "react-native-camera": "^2.11.0",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^0.7.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-pose": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.10.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "babel-jest": "24.8.0",
    "jest": "24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.54.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "private": true
}

```

Thank you in advance.
````

Comment: It could be that it is referenced in one of the packages you've added to your project. If this is the case, you might be able to rectify the issue by upgrading to a newer version if available. The fact you're on an old RN version could be the cause: `https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.0.tar.gz`

Answer (score 0):

ListView is a default Component.

You may use it in any Component.

It has been replaced by

`new list components, such as FlatList or SectionList for bounded memory use, fewer bugs, better performance, an easier to use API, and more features.`

You can read over this here:
[ListView](https://reactnative.dev/docs/listview.html)

Comment: im not using ListView anywhere in my project, but i'm having this issue

Comment: Maybe one of your Packages you have added uses ListView